# CAB Wizard - generating file list

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce, cab

Is there possible with CabWiz (or another utility) generate list of files on target device (with full path) included in CAB File for documentation purposes (readme.txt/info.txt)?

CAB file

In INF file this information in Sections [Files] and [DestinationDirs] presented

Should I develop my own parser or there are ready to use solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I use WinCE CAB Manager (http://www.ocpsoftware.com/products.php) for most of my CAB-related tasks.  You can dump a CAB to it's original parts, including creating the inf file.  Plus it's native "project" file is xml, which would make parsing the CAB information a breeze.